# MySQL counts and averages with group by

Tags: mysql, sql, join, group-by

I'll try and describe best I can. Working with a bad data model.

```
Table1
id, name, area, bla1, bla2, bla3

Table2
table1_ID, stuff1, stuff2, ID

trigger on table1
insert row in table2 if table1 is updated
```

In `table1` I have 10 different area, only 186 rows, not so much I can't do this manually in like 2 seconds with Excel but I want to create realtime report.

The report would be

```
area1 - %complete
area2 - %complete
area3 - %complete
etc.....
```

When a row is updated in `table1` the trigger inserts some stuff in table2 indicating 'complete'.

I can do (probably really bad form)

```
select
(select count(*) from table1 a where a.id in (select id from table2))
/
(select count(*) from table1)
*100
```

This gives me an overall percentage complete.
I was thinking of adding where clauses to each of the selects, hard coding 'area' and then union TEN times. Ugh, tell me there is a better way to get this in one report.

Obviously this query is a fail

```
select area,
(
(select count(*) from table1 a where a.id in (select id from table2))
/
(select count(*) from table1)
*100) from table1
group by area
```

I figure group by has got to fit in there somewhere. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select area, count(table2.table1_ID) / count(table1.id)
from table1 left join table2 on table1.id = table2.table1_ID
group by area
```

Comment: Thanks!! I am learning. The above was perfect. I added a union to give my report a total.